# Creating a Loop of Stars (Star Map)

Tags: c++, sfml

Hey so I'm trying to read from a file and basically create a cool star map.  I am totally a newb, and this is my first time playing with SFML.  I am working this on CLion.

I have used the Debugger and can see that everything is being properly put into it's place, but when I run the program the Window just ends up freezing not drawing anything.  I was unsure if it was my loop that is the problem or there is something else at play.  I didn't think I needed to use a vector since Vector2f seems to suffice ...Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

```
    CircleShape star;
    star.setRadius(2);
    while(!fileIn.eof()){

        fileIn >> xPixel >> yPixel >> brightStar;
        star.setPosition( Vector2f(xPixel, yPixel) );
        window.draw(star);

    }
    fileIn.close();
```

Draw Window just has the wheel of death and is "not responding"

Comment: Make the program a [mcve].

Comment: Recommendation: replace `while(!fileIn.eof()) { fileIn >> xPixel >> yPixel >> brightStar;` with `while(fileIn >> xPixel >> yPixel >> brightStar) { `. [Explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons). No clue if that will help you at all, but it's the only bug I see in the code provided. Please edit your way into a [mcve]. DO the [mcve] right and you'll probably solve the problem without any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Oh  now I put this in...

```
  CircleShape star;
    star.setRadius(2);
    while(!fileIn.eof()){

        fileIn >> xPixel >> yPixel >> brightStar;
        star.setPosition( Vector2f(xPixel, yPixel) );
        window.draw(star);
        CircleShape star;
        star.setRadius(2);
    }
    fileIn.close();
```

Star Map showed for a second then went away

Got it Yay:

```
    CircleShape star;
    star.setRadius(2);
    while(!fileIn.eof()){
        {
        fileIn >> xPixel >> yPixel >> brightStar;
        star.setPosition( Vector2f(xPixel, yPixel) );
        window.draw(star);
        CircleShape star;
        star.setRadius(2);}
        window.display();
    }
    fileIn.close();
```

Comment: Make edits to your original question to clarify it if you need to. Don't add proposed answers to the question - unless you have an actual answer.

Comment: I recommend editing this extra info into the question. It doesn't make for a particularly good answer

Comment: It looks like you missed the recommendation made by @user4581301  regarding using `while(!fileIn.eof())`.

Comment: Now that this does answer the question, I recommend making the need for `window.display();` brutally obvious. Mark it as an addition with a comment and briefly explain why it's needed (it'll be a really, really brief explanation). Definitely fix the `while(!eof)` bug. It's such a common and simple-to-fix mistake that it should never show up in an answer. Please notify me with an @ when you make the fix so I can upvote.